# fcgid is not handling. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, web-applications, mod-fcgid

I am using: apache2 2.4 on Ubuntu 23 / WT (webtoolkit witty).

I am trying to use WT with fcgid. My hello.conf file is:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName hello
    ServerAlias www.hello
    DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wt-examples/hello
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
    <Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wt-examples/hello/>
      Options +ExecCGI -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AllowOverride none
      Require ip 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

fcgid.conf is:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler fcgid-script .wt
  FcgidIPCDir /var/lib/apache2/fcgid
  FcgidIdleTimeout 100
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1
  FcgidInitialEnv WT_APP_ROOT=/var/www/localhost/htdocs/wt-examples/hello
  FcgidWrapper /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wt-examples/hello .wt
</IfModule>
```

I compiled hello.wt with libwtfcgid not libwthttpd. Used chown and chmod for myuser and web-data with 755 permission.

When I try to connect Apache error log shows: "*AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs/wt-examples/hello/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive*"

If use 127.0.0.1/hello.wt in the browser the error changes to: "*(104)Connection reset by peer: [client 127.0.0.1:37754] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server. [client 127.0.0.1:37754] End of script output before headers: hello.wt*"

If I put a regular text index.htlm it shows it.

I think the problem  was that fcgid was not handling. But now since it says "*End of script output before headers: hello.wt*", FastCGI receiving something but there is no header. So what is coming is not a proper page sent by hello.wt app. May be i should focus on WT configuration.

What is the problem do you think?

Comment: because hello.wt is no index file that has been declared

Comment: @djdomi I directly addressed hello.wt in the browser. FastCGI receives non proprer page. May be hello.wt is not running and fastcgi is reading the raw binary I don't know.